# Python Flask Application with Threads not running parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I am trying to build a Python program that sends data over UDP and has a website to make settings.
For this program, I need a script to run a flask webserver and a script to pull data at the same time. I want to use threading to run the processes (Flask server and the data pull/send part) at the same time.
Because I need to run the part to pull the data all the time, I made "While True:", so that it is always running
But when I start my threads only the Thread to pull data is running.
I think the problem is, that I don't really run 2 Threads at the same time. But I think with Threading it should be possible to run the flask Thread and the Data thread at the same time.
But I can't get it to work and I can't figure out the problem.

This is the file where I'm trying to start both threads:

```
import threading
import time
import mainl
import webserver

class mydata(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, iD, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.iD = iD
        self.name = name
    def run(self):
        mainl.mainloop()

class mywebserver(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, iD, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.iD = iD
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        webserver()

t1 = mydata(1, "t1")
t2 = mywebserver(2, "t2")
t2.start()
t1.start()
```

This is the file to pull data, which should always run, which is why i used "While True:":

```
def mainloop():
    while True:
        import data1
        import data2
        import data3

        ###UDP###
        ip_adress = "192.168.178.150"
        udp_port = 8888

        text = ""
        data1 = data1.daten()
        data2 = data2.daten()
        data3 = data3.daten()
        # print("Coin STR", coin)
        time.sleep(3)
        text = "data1   data2   data3"
        send.senden(ip_adress, udp_port, text)
```

Comment: Problem most likely lies in the webserver() function as the rest seems to work.

Comment: When I only start Webserver() the server is also working. But I found out, that mainl or mainl.mainloop() is not running from a thread. I dont know why its starting, but thread t1 and t2 don't even start because  mainl or mainl.mainloop() is already running before the threads start. Why is mainl or mainl.mainloop() already running? I think this will be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, the loop in the imports began while importing.
So the program did not continue.

Now I run the imports in a main function.

For more information I can recommend this:
https://www.guru99.com/learn-python-main-function-with-examples-understand-main.html